# Add tooltip to a dynamically created tabpage

Tags: c#, dynamic, tooltip, tabcontrol

I'm having a difficult time trying to work with tooltips.
I'm trying to add a tooltip with different text to each dynamically created tab in a tabcontrol.
It's important to note that this tab is created from a form that contains a docked form where the tabcontrol is in.
This is, a main Form with a docking area, in where I have docked a results form, which contains an - initially empty - tabcontrol.
When you start the application this results form doesnt exists, I also create it dynamically whenever the user press certains parts of the main form, each one created as a new tab in the results form tabcontrol.

This is how I generate the tabs:

```
      generateResultForm();

      TabPage newtp = new TabPage("Nuevo paciente")
      _result.TabControl.TabPages.Add(newtp);

      newtp.Name = setTabName("np");
```

Now, I've tried putting a tooltip in the results form, then tried to first generate the tooltip by adding below something like  `_result.ResultsTooltip.SetToolTip(newtp, "Creación de un nuevo paciente.");`, which didn't work. Then, since once the tab is created, it becomes selected, I tried to add it in the results class by something like `WorkareaTooltip.SetToolTip(tabControl.SelectedTab, "Cosas");` in the selectedindexchange event from the tabcontrol.
I don't think it would have been a great solution, but I don't know what else to try.

Of course the tabcontrol has its ShowToolTips property set to true.

If anyone could help me that'll be great.

Thanks for reading, and sorry if there are any language mistakes :)

//EDITED

This is the code i'm actually using (and doesn't work)

```
TabPage newtp = new TabPage("Nuevo paciente");
_workareaform.TabControl.TabPages.Add(newtp);
newtp.Name = "np";
var tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.SetToolTip(newtp, "Creación de un nuevo paciente.");
```

Now, it doesn't work, might be because of the whole configuration.
Just to be clear, this tab is in a TabControl which is in a Form docked into a dockContainer in another Form.
Here is an image if it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRzeb.png

As you can see, no tooltip at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `ToolTipText` property as shown below?. It worked for me.

```
_result.TabControl.ShowToolTips = true;
TabPage newtp = new TabPage("Nuevo paciente");
_result.TabControl.TabPages.Add(newtp);
newtp.ToolTipText = "this is tooltip";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with another form you need to reference the other form `TabControl`

In this sample I create a `Form1` instance (with `TabControl` in it) from my `Form2` and then add page and tooltip.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiate another form
    var f1 = new Form1();

    //find tabcontrol on new form
    var tc = (TabControl) f1.Controls["tabControl1"];

    //create page
    TabPage newtp = new TabPage("Nuevo paciente");
    newtp.Name = "Paciente1";
    tc.TabPages.Add(newtp);

    //add tooltip
    var tt1 = new ToolTip();
    tt1.SetToolTip(newtp, "paciente 1 tooltip");


    //show other form
    f1.Show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah... thats not working ^^u I think its because I'm creating the tab from another form, not the one containing it.

Comment: @Iskalla check my edit now, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to create a tooltip on another form. you're doing something wrong

Comment: I've checked it, and I just can't see any difference between your code and mine (not counting names, of course)
I'll give it a rest and try again a bit later with your solution, I must have some mistake I'm just not seeing.

Comment: @Iskalla can you show me a screenshot of your result form? maybe you're adding a tooltip to the wrong control (something that's not visible)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, but i've been quite busy with other parts of this project, and didn't have the time to look at this. 
I have edited the main post with an image of how it looks, and posted the code i'm currently using

Comment: @Iskalla thanks, I don't have the time to read it tho, I'm quite busy